# HSQLDB auto truncate

Tags: sql, hsqldb

Is possible to create a trigger or a parameter in connection String that truncate a varchar when it passes the limit?

I've tried to create a trigger Before insert/update but i continue to get the following exception:

java.io.IOException: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: data exception: string data, right truncation
    at org.apache.gora.sql.store.SqlStore.flush(SqlStore.java:340)
    at org.apache.gora.sql.store.SqlStore.close(SqlStore.java:185)

The gora is because i am using nutch.

Thanks

EDIT1:

The trigger is:
    CREATE TRIGGER  typeconversionUpdate  BEFORE  UPDATE  ON WEBPAGE
    REFERENCING NEW AS newrow
    FOR EACH ROW SET newrow.TEXT=''

And the create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE WEBPAGE (id VARCHAR(512) PRIMARY KEY,headers BLOB,text VARCHAR(32000),status INTEGER,markers BLOB,parseStatus BLOB,modifiedTime BIGINT,score FLOAT,typ VARCHAR(32),baseUrl VARCHAR(512),content BLOB(65536),title VARCHAR(512),reprUrl VARCHAR(512),fetchInterval INTEGER,prevFetchTime BIGINT,inlinks BLOB,prevSignature BLOB,outlinks BLOB,fetchTime BIGINT,retriesSinceFetch INTEGER,protocolStatus BLOB,signature BLOB,metadata BLOB)
```

Comment: Please include the CREATE TABLE and CREATE TRIGGER statements that you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to increase the maximum size of the column in question:

```
ALTER TABLE WEBPAGE ALTER COLUMN TEXT SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR(1000000)
```

The trigger solution cannot be used with HSQLDB up to version 2.2.9, but may be allowed in the next version.

Comment: Ok i will wait for next versions.

Meanwhile i've trucated the result in java code before the insert. I didn't want to alter the varchar length because the Strings can be very large, a full html page for example, but i only need some of the first characters.

Thanks.